How to compare 2 objects and return a property of the second object that is not in the comparison
I have a comparison to make between two lists, and for each item found, I have to return a property from the second list, I would like to do it via LINQ.
I have this class:
class Table
{
    private int hexToInt = 0;
    private string data = string.Empty;

    public int HexToInt { get => hexToInt; set => hexToInt = value; }
    public string Data { get => data; set => data = value; }

    public string Hex { get => hexToInt.ToString("X"); }
    public int HexSizeInBytes { get => Hex.Length / 2; }
}

I have a list of this same class:
List<Table> tableList = new List<Table>();

Table table = new Table();
table.HexToInt = 0;
table.Data = "a";
tableList.Add(table);

table = new Table();
table.HexToInt = 1;
table.Data = "b";
tableList.Add(table);

table = new Table();
table.HexToInt = 2;
table.Data = "c";
tableList.Add(table);

table = new Table();
table.HexToInt = 3;
table.Data = "d";
tableList.Add(table);

table = new Table();
table.HexToInt = 4;
table.Data = "d";
tableList.Add(table);

table = new Table();
table.HexToInt = 5;
table.Data = "f";
tableList.Add(table);

table = new Table();
table.HexToInt = 6;
table.Data = "g";
tableList.Add(table);

I also have a char array:
char[] charArray = new[] { 'c', 'a', 'a', 'f' };

I would like to take each item from the char array, search the Table list using the Data property, and if a match is found, return the HexToInt value. This return must be in a list, an example of the return list for the objects above:
List: [2, 0, 0, 5]
I tried this, but it doesn't work, because the Hex property is inaccessible in this context:
var test2 = dteCharArray.Where(x => table.Any(y => y.Data == x.ToString())).Select(y => y.Hex).ToList();


Performance-wise perhaps better to use a Dictionary than a List, keyed by the first char of Data e.g. var d = tableList.ToDictionary(e => e.Data[0]), as a one-time setup then you can dteCharArray.Select(c => d.TryGetValue(c, out var v) ? v.HexToInt : int.MinValue).Where(i => i > int.MinValue).ToList(). If you know all items in the char array will be in Data somewhere you can drop the Where and index the d directly like d[c]..

Also wish to point out that if the data is like this you can just dteCharArray.Select(c => c-'a').ToList()

"because the Hex property is inaccessible in this context", yes, starting from dteCharArray will mean you're running linq over a bunch of chars, not a bunch of Table objects so you don't have a Hex. Your Select can access the tableList (you wrote table.Any, but that's not your list of Tables btw) though so you could dteCharArray.Select(c => tableList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Data[0] == c)?.HexToInt) for a list of int? that you can then remove the nulls from. Caution though; this approach is effectively nested loops which is performance inefficient O(n^2)

tableList.Where(t => charArray.Contains(t.Data[0])).Select(table =>  table.HexToInt).ToList();
I changed the char array to list and I don't know if my assumption that the "Data" prop should be a char or not so I just indexed the first char for comparison.

@KhaledAyman that's something like the inverse of what is being requested

won't make a difference - I promise it will. Also, in your second suggestion(now deleted) with charArray.ForEach you seem to be going for either List.ForEach() with Array.ForEach; neither of these things are LINQ, charArray is not a List so ForEach(someDelegate) won't work on it, and Array.ForEach(T[], someDelegate) cannot be accessed from an instance

This will have to search the entry in tableList:
charArray.Select(x => tableList.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Data == x.ToString())?.HexToInt).ToList();

Oof, O(n^2) and a bucketload  of string allocations to boot?

Sure, but we know too little about the real use to consider performance issues, IMHO. As you correctly pointed out in one of your comments, this could even be an approach to hexadecimal parsing.

@KlausGütter, sorry, but I ended up specifying the output type as a list of int, when it should actually be an array of char. I need this arrayto rewrite a video game ROM file with a new recalculated DTE (Dual Tile Encoded) table. This array will have a maximum of 256 characters.

If you're mapping chars you can just make an array of char and index it by char; c# treats chars and ints equivalently for many operations. Example char[] c = ['d','e','f']; char old ='a'; char nuw = c[old - 'a']; - in this case 'a' becomes 'd', 'b' becomes 'e' etc. You don't need some complex "list of things here, that are looked up by looping through to find that thing there, then converting it..". If you truly are looking at conversions of hundreds or thousands of bytes then this On^2 approach performance could well be awful compared to alternatives like direct array or dictionary
